# placement delete inside or outside destructor

Tags: c++

I found the following code while reading placement new operator.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass {

public:
  // Placement new operator
  void* operator new (size_t sz, void* v) {
    cout << "Placement new invoked" << endl;
    return v;
  }

  ~MyClass() {
    // Cleanup
  }
};

int main()
{
    // Create a buffer to store the object
    int buffer[16];
    cout << "Starting address of my buffer = " << &buffer << endl;

    // Create the object. Use placement new
    MyClass* obj = new (buffer) MyClass();
    cout << "Location of my object = " << obj << endl;

    // Don't delete object created with placement delete
    // Call the destructor explicitly
    obj->~MyClass();
}
```

I have few questions related to delete object which was created using placement new:

1. what is the clean up code needs to write in destructor in order to
   free memory which was occupied obj in buffer memory.
2. is it not needed to define placement delete, if yes whether it needs to be inside destructor or outside destructor. If it is outside destructor how it will be called ?

Comment: You only need to call the destructor explicitly. Nothing to placement delete. (Note however, if the underlying buffer was allocated it may need deleting..)

Comment: read the two line comment at the end of the posted code

Comment: there is no such thing as placement-delete

Comment: @CashCow There is, but it's not relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the clean up code needs to write in destructor in order to free memory which was occupied obj in buffer memory

The destructor should just do what any destructor does: clean up any resources managed by the object. In this case, it doesn't manage any resources, so there's no need to do anything.

It shouldn't do anything special according to how the storage for the object itself was allocated. Managing that storage is the job for custom `new` and `delete` operators, when required.

> is it not needed to define placement delete

No. Placement-new is used to construct an object in storage that you're managing yourself, and it's your responsibility to free that storage yourself. In this case, the storage is automatic, so it's automatically freed when the function exits.

Just as the allocator for placement-new does nothing (just returning the provided pointer to pre-allocated storage), so the corresponding deallocator would do nothing; and so it doesn't exist. You just need to destroy the object by calling its destructor directly, before disposing of the storage yourself.

Comment: §18.6.1.3 defines a global `operator delete( void*, void* )`; if
he defines a class specific `operator new( size_t, void* )`, it
would probably be good form to define the corresponding
`operator delete` as well, in case the constructor throws.  If
nothing else, it will ensure that a delete on a pointer to the
object will not find the global `operator delete` (which is not
likely to work with his placement `operator new`).

Comment: @JamesKanze, For the above code, could you please define operator delete. If I call delete of obj, wihtout defining operator delete, what will be the impact?

Comment: @Mike, Consider above example with a integer private data member,then MyClass* obj = new (buffer) MyClass(); will allocate 4bytes of memory for obj, in buffer. Now can u explain how to delete the obj memory from buffer, so that buffer retain its old state.

Comment: @user3665615: I don't know what you mean. Placement-new won't allocate memory from the buffer (whatever you think that means); it will use (some of) the buffer's memory as storage for the object it creates. There's no corresponding delete; you must destroy the object (by calling its destructor) before you deallocate or reuse the buffer. The whole point of placement-new is that it doesn't allocate memory; it allows you to create and destroy objects in storage that you manage yourself. If you don't want to manage the storage yourself, don't use placement-new.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, Thanks for your reply. My doubt is how to write destructor for class which has int member (not pointer), so that I can reuse the buffer.

Comment: @user3665615: There's no need for the destructor to do anything with an `int` member, since `int` is trivially destructable. Just call the class destructor (that's optional, if the whole class is trivially destructible, but a good idea in case you add a non-trivial member later), then reuse the buffer.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, I suppose if you wrote your own placement allocator to do something weird, then you might need a corresponding deallocator to undo the weirdness. I'm just describing regular placement-new, since that seems to be the scope of the question (give or take adding logging to the default placement allocator without otherwise changing its behaviour).

Comment: @MikeSeymour, Sorry I am not able to understand your answer. I will rephrase my question. lets assume I have a memory of 100 bytes and I created object using placement new which has int member (not pointer), which will occpy 4 bytes. later if i want to destroy object so that 4 bytes will be released from buffer, so that my buffer will contain total memory of 100 bytes

Comment: @user3665615: As I said: destroy the object by calling its destructor, exactly as in the code you've posted. Then you can reuse the buffer. There's no concept of "allocating" or "releasing" memory from the buffer; you're simply using (part of) the buffer to store the object, and you can reuse it once you've destroyed the object.

Comment: @MikeSeymour,As you said in case of int member no need of destructor, it is trivially destructable.  Can you please explain what is menat by trivially destructable, if I dont call destructor, how to destroy object(int member) so that 100bytes will be available to buffer.

Comment: @user3665615: Sorry to keep repeating myself, but I can't it any clearer: Destroy the object by calling its destructor. Then you can reuse the buffer. All 100 bytes are still there in any case - they haven't gone anywhere, they've just had an object created and destroyed on top of them. (A "trivially destructible" type means that you don't have to do anything special to destroy it; basic types like `int` are trivial, as is your class if it simply contains an `int`. That means you could just reuse the buffer without calling the destructor, but it's a good idea to call it anyway.)

Comment: @MikeSeymour It's not rare to define a placement new which takes an identifier of a pool as an argument; making it work requires memorizing the pool id somewhere for each block, or being able to deduce it from the address, and implementing a non-placement delete (as well as a placement delete) which determines which pool to use for the freeing of the memory.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Indeed, there are plenty of uses for custom placement-new overrides; but that's got nothing to do with this question, which (at least by my reading) is about the use of default placement-new to create an object in pre-allocated memory. That's what my answer describes, and there's more than enough discussion of that already without going off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Regular `new` does two things:

1. allocate memory for your object
2. construct your object in that memory space.

Placement `new` means you manage one of those and the other is managed as before.

1. You allocate / provide the memory for your object
2. Constructor is called in that memory space.

The reverse is `delete` of which the regular `delete` does the following:

1. Invoke the destructor of the object to clean-up
2. Free the memory that was allocated for it.

Note that they are done in reverse order for obvious reasons. You cannot free the memory that contains information about what needs to be cleaned up, unti you have finished using that memory. Whereas in construction you need to get hold of the memory first.

In what you call placement delete but is really the reverse of placement new, you need to perform the first step of destruction but not the second. Thus you call the object's destructor, and then you can free up the memory it uses / use it for something else.

The most common example of usage of placement new is in the implementation of `std::vector` which requires a contiguous buffer for its data, and which lets you reserve ahead (and if you don't it will probably do it for you). That part allocates the memory but does not construct the objects in it. Thus when they are constructed later, placement new is used.

Comment: Actually, placement new can mean two different things.  In the generic meaning, it means that you can pass additional arguments to the `operator new` function; the types and what they mean is up to you.  The term may also be used for one particular variant of placement new, where there is one additional `void*` argument, which is just returned.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to ask is: what are you trying to do?  If you
define a placement operator new in a class, then that is the
only operator new which will be found when you write `new
MyClass`; you *must* always specify the extra arguments.  And in
almost every case where you define a class specific `operator
new`, you should also define a class specific `operator delete`;
otherwise the global `operator delete` function will be called
when you write `delete p`, and that generally won't work.

If your goal is to systematically require separation of
allocation and initialization, and that is why you are defining
a member operator new, then you can provide a no-op `operator
delete`; if the constructor of the class can throw, then you'll
also want to provide a placement operator delete, since this is
what will be called if the constructor of a newed object exits
via an exception.  There is no other way to call it, however.
When providing placement operator new, you must provide
a default operator delete which does the right thing; and when
providing several operator new for the same type, you need to
memorize somehow in each allocation which one was called, in
order to dispatch in the non-placement operator delete.

And by the way, just allocating a buffer as a local variable
does *not* guarantee sufficient alignment for anything but the
declared buffer type.

EDIT:

Just an example of what would be needed for the `operator
delete` functions (which must be members):

```
void operator delete( void* p ) {}
void operator delete( void* p, void* ) {}
```